# Change arguments in view

Tags: views

I have a view with arguments in the page and attachment displays.

When I go to the view page, I see a list of arguments (links) because in "Action to take if argument is not present" I selected  "Summary, sorted ascending."

How do I sort arguments (in this case is term) by weight? I don't see any option to do this. Where can I change the query "ORDER BY term ASC" to "ORDER BY weight ASC" in code?

When I click an argument, I have another page with a list of arguments again, because I have an attachment. How do I only show the argument name I have clicked?

Answer (score 1):

you are using drupal 6, or drupal 7?

If I understand well your questions:

you can change the query used to generate view results (Order BY, Where, etc) using query_alter hook. here one example: [Making a field sortable in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11110/making-a-field-sortable-in-views)

About weight of arguments, I think that you can control order of precedence in 'rearrange' option:

[image]

If your question is related with weight of taxonomy terms, in your View settings > Add sort criteria > Taxonomy: Weight seems will be useful to sort according weight of each term:

[image]

regarding shows argument clicked, you can get argument from the current url easily using `arg()` http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7:

example URL: `http://example.com/node/12345/edit`

in this example

`arg(0)` is `node`

`arg(1)` is `12345`

`arg(2)` is `edit`

here some experiences in Drupal forum to review, with or without using arg():

http://drupal.org/node/180589

http://drupal.org/node/283945

you can add a php code to get respective argument, for example using arg() in a view header or in a drupal php node/page/block:

`<?php echo arg(0); ?>` or `<?php echo arg(1); ?>` according your target argument.

I hope information be useful.

Comment: i use drupal 6. about "weight of arguments, I think that you can control order of precedence in 'rearrange' option:" i see one "taxonomy:term" no term list to sort.

Comment: I think that you can use `query_alter` hook to review if you can alter the query according your needs. here is some guidance about what is `query_alter` hook http://drupal.org/node/1029634

Comment: I have updated my answer with a comment about sorting results of your view, according weight of taxonomy terms.

Comment: thank u but it sort nodes, not arguments. i want to sort arguments (in this case taxonomy term) order by term weight.

Comment: then `query_alter` will be useful for you.